# Creating src folder for new modules on Intellij 2019.2.1 CE

Tags: intellij-idea

I have recently upgraded to Intellij 2019.2.1 CE and created a new project with several modules. The new modules are created with only the `build.gradle` file. The src folder is missing.

On previous version, there was an option under `Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> check the "Create directories for empty content roots automatically".` to remedy this.

The new version does not have this option.

[image: screenshot]

How do I get IntelliJ to generate the folders as before?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative will be provided in 2019.3 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216938